# Formula to add values in column G only if cells in Column B contain a "X"

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that lists bank transactions.  If the specific transaction is for a "school-related" cost, ie. Tuition, I have an "X" in column D.  I want to create a cell that will give me the total dollars for all the items in column G that have an "X" in column D.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sample data will help here. Also, sounds like a pivot table is a better way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @Gary's Student, a simpler version of this formula is to use SUMIFS. For the range he posted above, consider using

```
=SUMIFS(G:G,D:D,"X")
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will have to study the exact context of the formula to know exactly what it does,

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.  Here is an example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(D:D="X")*(G:G))
```

[image]

You naturally would tailor this to match your data schema.
For example, you could use column **B** rather than column **D**.